# IT Hit WebDAV Sample App not running with tomcat

Tags: ithit-webdav-server

I have downloaded the sample app [ITHitWebDAVServerLibJava.tar.gz] trying to understand how this IT Hit Webdav work.

I started the demo app with Tomcat 8, running on JDK 1.8. From the tomcat console / log, it seems everything just fine, however when I access the main page, it doesn't list out the sample folders & files as how it suppose to (referring to the online demo).
[screen : main page is render without listing out the folders & files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cEqr.png)

I downloaded the sample app and unzip it, without changing the folder structure of it. I have just edited the WEB-INF\web.xml so that it point to the correct trial license file. Please advise if I have missed out some configuration? Should I move out certain files from the WEB-INF folder? Is there any step by step setup guide this demo?
[screen : unzipped sample app folder without changing the folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJRJD.png)

Also, I have downloaded the trial version of AJAX library as well [ITHitWebDAVAJAXLibraryTrial.tar.gz], please advise how should I put this library into the main sample app? As in I should put this library files under which folder of the main sample app?

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default HTML page supplied with IT Hit WebDAV Server Library for Java sample servers use IT Hit WebDAV Ajax Library to list and browse WebDAV server content as well as to open documents for editing.

You can install IT Hit WebDAV Ajax Library from [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webdav.client) using NPM command-line tool.

1. Install the Node.js, it installs NPM command-line tool.
2. Navigate to '\sample_folder\WEB-INF\wwwroot\' folder.
3. Execute:

   ```
   npm install webdav.client
   ```

This will download IT Hit WebDAV Ajax Library library into the wwwroot folder.

Comment: Thanks. It works now after I use the NPM command to download the IT HitWebDAV Ajax Library

Comment: Anyway, may I know what is this [ITHitWebDAVAJAXLibraryTrial.tar.gz] that we could download from your official website? How is it different than the one I downloaded via the NPM command?

Comment: It has the same content. NPM is getting more popular for JavaScript projects, so we are working to move part of the projects to NPM and see pros and cons.